# Issue with nested struct in Go

Tags: go, struct

I have two structs A & B and a nested struct C with A & B, defined as below:

Struct A :

```
type Source_a struct{
        Sname string
        price float64
        Qty int
    }
```

Struct B :

```
type Source_b struct{
        Sname2 string
        price2 float64
        Qty2 int
        }
```

Nested Struct C :

```
type Data struct{

    S_a []Source_a
    S_b []Source_b 
}
```

I have declared the Source_a & Source_b type var and derived & assigned the values to it from DB. Sample code for Struct A:

```
//Post DB query
sks := make([]Source_a, 0)
for rows.Next(){
sk := Source_a{}
err := rows.Scan(&sk.Sname, &sk.Uprice, &sk.Qty)
sks = append(sks, sk)
```

I am having trouble in binding the values of Struct A & B to Struct C. I am trying something but it is throwing errors, pretty sure this is not the correct way:

```
td := Data{
      S_a: []Source_a{
           Source_a{
           Sname:sks.Sname,
           Uprice:sks.Uprice,
           Qty:sks.Qty,
           },
         },
      S_b: []Source_b{
           Source_b{
           Sname2: sks2.Sname2,
           Uprice2: sks2.Uprice2,
           Qty2: sks2.Qty2,
           },
        },              
    },
```

Can you please help, I am new to Golang. Let me know if you need clarifications or specifics.

Comment: @mkopriva, Can you please help?

Comment: What errors are you getting specifically? Can you edit and include them in the question?

Comment: I strongly recommend working through the whole Tour of Go once more.

Answer (score 2):

`sks` and `sks2` seem like slices and you are using them as variables. You can do

```golang
td := Data{
      S_a: sks,
      S_b: sks2,             
}
```